# Why this PHP captcha script I found is not working

Tags: php, html, captcha

I use this script: [link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/a-simple-php-captcha-script/) and the demo works fine on the internet, but when I download it and run, the captcha image doesn't show. Why? Any advice, or any other simple captcha script?
P.S. I can't use any google service because I'm in China.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I mean the captcha image doesn't appear.

Comment: @David, You can upvote/accept my answer if it really helps to you to resolve your problem. Let me know if you still have any issues.Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David, **Please check below link** for alternate solution of your problem.

It's very easy to integrate in to your form. Also They have explained in very detail so very easy to understand the code.

Please [click](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/php-captcha-code.html) here.

Let me know if you have still any issues.

Comment: Sorry PHPWeblineindia but it still not working, here is my screenshot: [ScreenShot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3gOdVwMWA-vYXFsTzhXS0tDYzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry I can't able to see your screen. What's error you're getting ? can you please let me know issues ?

Comment: it's on my screenshot, I use the method which was in you link, the issue is, the captcha image didn't show and seems it's broken.

Comment: @David, I think GD library missing at your end. Please check this link for GD library becuase GD library generate captcha images. Check [this](http://www.zoopable.com/check-php-gd-library-installed-or-not/)

Comment: Checking. @PHPWeblineindia

Comment: Here is the result on my phpinfo():
GD Support enabled
GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support enabled
FreeType Linkage with freetype
FreeType Version 2.4.10
GIF Read Support enabled
GIF Create Support enabled
JPEG Support enabled
libJPEG Version 9 compatible
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version 1.5.18
WBMP Support enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version 30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support enabled

Comment: @David, Make sure captcha.php & cap_bg.jpg file is as same directory as index.php file.

Comment: Wait a second...checking

Comment: Can you send me your source code project in zip? I think I did miss something. @PHPWeblineindia

Comment: @David, Please download it from [here](http://demos.9lessons.info/url.php?url=http://www.box.net/shared/qkmgvef1nq) & extract in to your project space otherwise directly it won't work. Which server you are using ?

Comment: Wamp @PHPWeblineindia

Comment: It works!!!!!! Thank you @PHPWeblineindia!! This problem had bothered me for a hole day now finally been solved!!!Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad ! I could help to resolve your problem. Can you please accept my answer @David ?

Comment: And wait for I get 15+ reputation so I can vote up your answer.